# Ionic just displaying blank page when running ionic serve --lab

Tags: macos, ionic-framework

I am developing an Ionic app with a friend who is developing in Windows. I had all the code working fine on a Windows machine but have now upgraded to a more powerful Mac machine.

When running the app on my Mac using:

> ionic serve --lab

[I get a blank screen like this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueC5z.png)

and the following errors come up in the Chrome console.

```
   http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/angular-applicationinsights/dist/angular-applicationinsights.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)


ionic.bundle.js:13217 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ApplicationInsightsModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ApplicationInsightsModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ApplicationInsightsModule
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8900:12
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10790:17
    at ensure (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10714:38)
    at module (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10788:14)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13194:22
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13195:40
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ApplicationInsights…%2F%2F192.168.0.21%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13178%3A5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8900:12
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13217:15
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13195:40
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at createInjector (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13104:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10462:20)
    at bootstrap (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10483:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2F192.168.0.21%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10483%3A12)


ionic.bundle.js:13217 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ApplicationInsightsModule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ApplicationInsightsModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ApplicationInsightsModule
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8900:12
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10790:17
    at ensure (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10714:38)
    at module (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10788:14)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13194:22
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13195:40
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=ApplicationInsights…%2F%2F192.168.0.21%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13178%3A5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:8900:12
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13217:15
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13195:40
    at forEach (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9168:20)
    at loadModules (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13178:5)
    at createInjector (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13104:11)
    at doBootstrap (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10462:20)
    at bootstrap (http://192.168.0.21:8100/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10483:12)
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=Error%3A%20%…2F%2F192.168.0.21%3A8100%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10483%3A12)
```

A little bit of research leads me to think this is because we are developing across two different platforms. Could be barking up the wrong tree there though.

Does anyone know how to resolve these issues and get Ionic running please? Thanks.

Comment: "You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it..!" check index.html,have u added script..! and app.js, hav u added module name as dependency..![This](http://kenhaines.net/adding-application-insights-to-an-angularjs-application/) might be help..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The was resolved by running

> brower install

in the directory. That seemed to sort out the browser module dependencies.